# ASPX Page (vb.net) with dynamic controls created at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a nested content page within a master page, upon load the the page retrieves from a SQL a list of controls to create (Field Type, FieldName) i.e. String, Username.

The function loops around the list creating the controls on the webform in a Placeholder, this part works perfectly.  The problem that I am experiencing is the request to obtain the value entered by the user in the dynamically created control, I need to perform this call following postback/callback.

If I take the Content page and make it a standard aspx page with no master page the application works fine.  Unfortunatley taking the page out of the master page is not an option (unfortunatley a restriction by my client)

I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What event are you populating your dynamic controls?

Comment: I call a function on PageLoad

Comment: On Page load i call  If Not IsPostBack AndAlso Not IsCallback Then LOADCONTROLS End If and then I have a button that the user clicks (the contents of the controls should then be entered to SQL) this causes a postback and I need to retrieve the values at this point.

Comment: Can you move the control population logic to OnInit?  OnInit happens before viewstate is loaded and OnLoad happens after viewstate is loaded.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Comment: OnInit wont work, at this stage the controls have been created according to the MSDN page you provided "the postback data has not yet been loaded and control property values have not been restored to the values from view state."

Comment: @WaltersSean - You ever find a solution for this?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one of the dynamically added controls is a textbox you could do something like this...

```
Dim strValueOfDynamicControl As String = CType(YourPlaceHolder.FindControl("IdOfDynamicallyAddedControl"), TextBox).Text
```

Comment: Its not so much obtaining the value, I think its more to do with viewstate, because after the controls have been postback/callback on the submit button, the values are lost.

Comment: Add the Dynamic controls in the Page's Init event.

Comment: OnInit wont work, at this stage the controls havent been created, the postback data has not yet been loaded and control property values have not been restored to the values from view state."